# Is it possible to list the usages of an item from ReusableContent

Tags: 2010, publishing-page, publishing

Actually this is two questions...

- When looking at Page-Content (content of a publishing Page) in edit-mode: Is there a way to determine if a block of content is a Reusable Content? And which one?
- Can I somehow list all usages of a specific Reusable Content item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Question 1: If I hadn't deleted the reference to `edit-mode-21.css` I would have seen what is ReusableContent.

To Question 2: No. (Sadly...)